# adding HttpParams to HttpClient return server error (400) in android

Tags: java, android, http, httpclient

i simply to understand how but this are the fact

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

**work fine .**

but this  :

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```

returned server error (400)

how could it be ? i didn't changed anything but adding empty params ....

i also check the fields of the httpClient and i didnt saw anything diffrent

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpParams` values that are included in a new `DefaultHttpClient` contain some basic headers (like user agent and protocol version), while a brand new `BasicHttpParams` is completely empty.

```
http.protocol.expect-continue=false, 
http.protocol.version=HTTP/1.1, 
http.protocol.content-charset=ISO-8859-1, 
http.useragent=Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
```

Your server is probably expecting at least some of them, hence the "bad request" response.

If you need to add custom parameters, you should start with `httpClient.getParams()` and build them from there.